# Python: pandas.replace doesn't work with np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, replace, nan

I wanted to replace [`np.nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.nan) with `None` values, but weird behaviour occurred:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', np.nan, 'rabbit'])
>>> s = s.replace(np.nan, None)
>>> print(s)
0       cat
1       dog
2       dog
3    rabbit
dtype: object
```

How can [`np.nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.nan) be replaced with `'dog'` string? I do not understand. Can you explain it to me, please?

---

I found out that this code works as expected, so the right solution answers are not necessary.

```
s = s.replace({np.nan: None})
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), when `value=None` the method="pad" is used. (from the information about the last parameter **method**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

> ```
> >>> s = pd.Series([10, 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'])
> ```
>
> When `value=None` and *to_replace* is a scalar, list or tuple, *replace*
> uses the method parameter (default ‘pad’) to do the replacement. So
> this is why the ‘a’ values are being replaced by 10 in rows 1 and 2
> and ‘b’ in row 4 in this case. The command `s.replace('a', None)` is
> actually equivalent to `s.replace(to_replace='a', value=None, method='pad')`:
>
> ```
> >>> s.replace('a', None)
> 0    10
> 1    10
> 2    10
> 3     b
> 4     b
> dtype: object
> ```

Answer (score -1):

the second parameter is none, so it equals`s.replace(np.nan)`
you can try replase all of the 'nan'using : `df = df.fillna(value='')`,it will replace all nan with ''